# Running splash dialog while running heavy task in another dialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I'm trying to implement a task as described in the caption.
The HeaviWindow performs some heavy task and so not displayed until the task finished. This time I want to display a splash screen with animated loader.

Till now I used the following construction:

```
private RunHeavyTask()
{
    ShowSplashScreen("Please wait...");
    var dialog = new HeaviWindow();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}

private void ShowSplashScreen(string str)
{
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start(str);
}

private void ThreadStartingPoint(object str)
{
    splash = new WaitWindow((string)str);
    splash.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

But suddenly it turned out that while running the thread all other background threads stop to work.

I've tried to use `Task` for this purpose:

```
private void ShowSplashScreen(string str)
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
        {
            splash = new WaitWindow((string)str);
            splash.ShowDialog();
        });
    });
}
```

But splash screen not displayed until the heavy dialog finish the task. The same result if I use `BackgroundWorker`.

So my question - how can I display a splash dialog while running a heavy task in another one. The splash dialog use some animation so it need to be updated.

Comment: `But splash screen not displayed until the heavy dialog finish the task` calling `ShowDialog` will block execution until it's done, this is normal.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ exactly, the question is how can I avoid that.

Comment: What is more important here is what is going on in your `HeaviWindow` a dialog needs to display in the UI thread, but if your `HeaviWindow` is performing it's work on the UI thread or it is not using threading at all, then your calls to start a new thread have to wait for the `HeaviWindow` to free up the UI thread to display the splash screen.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller the HeavyWindow not displayed until the task finished, that's ok for me but I want to display the Splash screen instead. when HeavyWindow finishes the task it will be displayed and so I close the splash screen in this moment.

Comment: Why are you starting the splash screen from another thread? This is not necessary and doesn't make much sense. You should show the window before you start the worker thread. Why shouldn't this work for you.

Comment: If I start the splash screen in the same thread as HeavyWindow i.e. in the UI thread it will be blocked and will not be updated while heavy task executed.

Comment: No, that's only because you are obviously doing something totally wrong. You can have the main window, which starts a second window and a dialog while all windows will remain responsive in terms of rendering time. Of course the modal dialog will capture the device input. Please show the problematic code. I guess it is the code that updates the splash screen from the background thread?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Window splash;
private void RunHeavyTask()
{
    ShowSplashScreen("Please wait...");
    //simulate "heavy task" by sleeping for 5 seconds
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //close the splash window
    splash.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => splash.Close());
}

private void ShowSplashScreen(string str)
{
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        //pass str to your custom Window here...
        splash = new Window() { Content = new ProgressBar() { IsIndeterminate = true } };
        splash.Closed += (s, e) =>
           Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

        splash.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }));
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start();
}
```

It will display a window with an indeterminate `ProgressBar` on a background thread while the thread that calls `RunHeavyTask()` is blocked.

Comment: Thanks @mm8 for the response.  This code is almost the same that I already have. The problem that `SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` blocks another background threads, in my case this is unacceptable.

Comment: @folibis: What is blocking what? You have `ApartmentState.STA` in your example as well. This is a hard requirement for the all window threads.

Comment: Yes, and that's a problem. I have several threads that run in background. After running the Splash screen thread with  `SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` all these threads are blocked.

Comment: @folibis: Please prove your point with a minimal example.

Comment: I've provided the code in the question above. That the code that I use now.

Comment: @folibis: And I have provided some code that works. Or what thread do you mean is blocked in your example...?

Comment: My code works well too except the fact that it blocks the background threads. I can add these threads but that say nothing, It's several `BackgroundWorker` instances with some simple tasks.

Comment: "The  background threads"? How many are there, what to they do and how are they created, etc? What hardware are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what *exactly* you are trying to do. More details would be nice as it seems that your general approach needs to be optimized.

Generally you don't start the `Window` in a separate thread to execute heavy work (CPU bound) on the UI thread.  Rather would you execute the CPU intensive task on a background thread. You can wait for this task asynchronously and then close the splash screen afterwards when the task has completed.

The following simple example shows the pattern to be used to execute the CPU bound work asynchronously on a background thread to keep the UI thread responsive, while using [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netcore-3.1) to access the UI thread from the background thread using a delegate registered with an instance of [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netcore-3.1).
The example assumes that the splash screen is showing some progress and for this purpose exposes a `Progress` property:

```
// Show a splash screen,
// while executing CPU bound work asynchronously on a background thread
private async Task RunHeavyTaskAsync()
{
  splashScreen = new Window();
  splashScreen.Show();
 
  // Use IProgress<T> to access the UI thread via a delegate,
  // which is registered using the constructor of Progress<T>
  var progressReporter = new Progress<double>(value => splashScreen.Progress = value);

  // Pass the IProgress<T> instance to the background thread
  // and wait non-blocking (asynchronously) for the thread to complete
  await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progressReporter));

  // Close splash screen after 5s heavy work
  splashScreen.Close();
}

// Will be executed on a background thread
private void DoWork(IProgress<double> progressReporter)
{
  // Post progress from background thread (current context)
  // to the UI thread (splash screen).
  // IProgress<T>.Report() will execute the previously registered delegate
  progressReporter.Report(50);

  // Do 5s heavy work
  Thread.Sleep(5000);

  progressReporter.Report(100);
}
```